# Best translation of 今日も始まる

Tags: song-lyrics, particle-も

In [these lyrics](http://www.kget.jp/lyric/64673/WE+ARE+SAINT+%EF%BD%9E%E7%A5%9E%E8%A9%B1%E3%81%AE%E8%AA%93%E3%81%84%EF%BD%9E_%E5%BD%B1%E5%B1%B1%E3%83%92%E3%83%AD%E3%83%8E%E3%83%96%2C+BROADWAY), I came across the following verses:

```
夜明けの光り 眩しい仲間
宇宙の神話 今日もはじまる
未来をめざして
```

Does the particle も indicate emphasis of 今日 in this case?
My best guess is that the second line should be translated as "It is now that the mythology of the universe begins" (in the sense that the it starts right now, not in another situation). 
Translating the sentence as "The mythology of the universe *also* starts today" sounds unfamiliar.

Comment: そうですか...厳しいな。僕には、OPが sounds unfamiliarと言っている解釈が正しいように思えます。

Comment: 宇宙の神話が今日**もまた**始まる the mythology of the universe starts **again** today って意味じゃないんですかね？ 「夜明けの」って書いてあるんで、朝みたいだし。。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 夜明{よあ}けの光{ひか}り 眩{まぶ}しい仲間{なかま}
>
> 宇宙{うちゅう}の神話{しんわ} 今日{きょう}**も**はじまる
>
> 未来{みらい}をめざして

Your question has already been answered by @Chocolate above, so all I am doing would be to add my own perspective.

The second line would mean:

> "A/The mythology of the universe starts again today."

It is "today too" and not "mythology too" because 「も」 generally modifies the immediately preceding word.

Why use "today" at all in the first place?  IMHO, that would be because this is a theme for anime, correct?  In a televised anime series, the viewers would naturally tend to expect an interesting story to take place in each episode.  By saying 「宇宙の神話 **今日も**はじまる」, it inspires a feeling of hope that something exciting would happen ***again today*** in the episode that one is about to watch.

In that sense, one could say that the lyrics for anime themes can be subtly "*commercially manipulated*" like this.  In other words, anime theme lyrics should not be analyzed too straightforwardly using the regular prose/composition grammar or phrasing.